# iTunes Connect Message: Invalid Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, libraries

After submitting my binary to iTunes Connect, I receive an email stating:

> **Invalid Bundle** - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.

The only external library I'm using is ios-charts, which I installed **manually** (ie. not with Cocoapods; most of the online solutions to this I've found are based on cleaning your Cocoapods). How can I go about fixing this? The project is in Swift if it's relevant.

Comment: i assume you already asked your friend google? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Invalid+Bundle+-+One+or+more+dynamic+libraries+that+are+referenced+by+your+app+are+not+present+in+the+dylib+search+path.

Comment: Yes, the results related to this message all seem to be Cocoapods related.

Comment: I just had to use itunes connect and I ran into a plethora of errors, I think that was one of them... I was able to solve all my issues by following these helpful links ... http://www.raywenderlich.com/48750/testflight-sdk-tutorial  and http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial